# SlideToggle Div Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following jQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $('.totalthing').slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        $('.expandedcase').slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

At the moment it closes one of the div's and opens another at the same time. What I want it to do is close the open div then once it is fully closed it opens the other.

Comment: see  this  [http://jsfiddle.net/gwLcD/27/](http://jsfiddle.net/gwLcD/27/)

Comment: Why leave the relevant HTML out of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
       var tot = $('.totalthing');
       var exp = $('.expandedcase');

       var frt = (tot.is(":visible"))?tot:exp;
       var lst = (tot.is(":visible"))?exp:tot;

       frt.stop().slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {
          lst.stop().slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {/*complete*/});
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: works great thanks, I also have another issue. It works on the first time however when it is showing the .totalthing div it slows down to a stop and then jumps to reveal the last 25px or so. DCo you think this is due to padding or margins i can not seem to figure out why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments should point you in the right direction.  If you want one animation to start once the other is complete, then move it to the function.

```
$(function() {
$('.clickme').click(function() {
$('.totalthing').slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.expandedcase').slideToggle('slow','easeInOutQuart', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

});
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this so it will reverse the order on the next click? or do i have to create a second function for that?

Comment: You could add and remove classes to indicate the state and just toggle them on / off.